# How to trace this recursive program

Tags: python, recursion

I was wondering if someone would be able to tell me how this program arrives at the correct answer. I have tried to trace it and am not sure where to go because it has an `or`, so I am confused, how it is supposed to be traced. Thanks for any clarification.

Write a function partition that takes a list of numbers `xs`, a starting position `i`, and a desired sum `s` and returns `True` or `False` depending on whether it is possible to find a subsequence of the list elements starting from position `i` whose sum is exactly `s`. Note that it is always possible to produce a subsequence of elements whose sum is exactly 0, namely the empty sequence of elements.

```
def partition(xs,i,s):
    print i,s
    if i == len(xs):
        return s == 0
    else:
        return partition(xs,i+1,s-xs[i]) or partition(xs,i+1,s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [rcviz](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz) module is a nice tool to help to visualise recursive functions:

[image]

> The edges are numbered by the order in which they were traversed by the execution. 2. The edges are colored from black to grey to indicate order of traversal : black edges first, grey edges last.

If you follow the calls which are numbered *1-11* you can see exactly what is happening, `i` starts at `0` then goes to 1, 2 3 and finally 4, the last value on the left is `partitition([1,2,3,4],4,-2)` so it returns False for `s == 0`.

Next we go back to where `i` is `2` then again 3,4 and end up with `partitition([1,2,3,4],4,1)` so `s == 1` again is `False`.

Next  we go from step `6` ending with `partitition([1,2,3,4],4,5)` where yet again `s == 0` is False.

Finally in the right we go from `partitition([1,2,3,4],4,7)` all the way down to `partitition([1,2,3,4],4,0)` where `s == 0` is True and the function returns `True`.

If you take the first four calls, you can see how the flow goes and how s is changed.

```
 partitition([1,2,3,4],1,7)  # -> xs[i] = 1 s - 1 = 7
 partitition([1,2,3,4],2,5)  # -> xs[i] = 2 s - 2 = 5
 partitition([1,2,3,4],2,5)  # -> xs[i] = 3 s - 3 = 2
 partitition([1,2,3,4],2,5)  # -> xs[i] = 4 s - 4 = -2
 s == 0 # -> False
```

Comment: Hey is this Padraic itself? The formatting is soo nice!

Comment: @BhargavRao, yep I know you would be around ;)

Comment: You've reduced my job, I'll hafta look up classifieds :(  ... But there! You've missed a comma between 2 and 3 ... :P

Comment: @BhargavRao, maybe I did it on purpose ;)

Comment: Then bring your parents tomorrow! I will have to speak to them :P

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this version, which is logically equivalent, makes it a bit clearer.  The key is that `return a or b` is equivalent to `if a: return a else: return b`.

```
def partition(xs,i,s):
print i,s
if i == len(xs):
    # Base case: If the goal is to sum to 0, we succeed.
    return s == 0
else:
    # First, try including element i in our sum:
    first_try = partition(xs,i+1,s-xs[i])
    if first_try:
        return True
    else:
        # If first try failed, try not including element i
        second_try = partition(xs,i+1,s)
        return second_try
```

Comment: or `return True if a else False` :)

Comment: @Zizouz212: I think you meant `return True if a else b`; what you wrote doesn't check `b` at all. Also, that isn't really any easier to trace than `return a or b`, since it's still cramming both recursive calls into a single expression rather than putting them in separate statements that can be stepped over.

Answer (score 0):

This is an explanation of how `or` works in this context:

```
return partition(xs,i+1,s-xs[i]) or partition(xs,i+1,s)
```

will return `partition(xs,i+1,s-xs[i])` if this expression evaluates to `True`.  If `partition(xs,i+1,s-xs[i])` evaluates to `False`, `partition(xs,i+1,s)` will be returned (regardless of whether it evaluates to `True` or `False`).

Note you can test this with the following set of simple examples:

```
In [1]: 1 or 2  # When both are True, the first is returned.
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: 0 or 2  # When the first is False, the second is returned.
Out[2]: 2

In [4]: 0 or False  # When both are False, the second is returned.
Out[4]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it becomes a lot easier to understand if it's written with better names and no indexing:

```
def can_add_to(numbers, sumwanted):
    if not numbers:
        return sumwanted == 0
    first, *rest = numbers
    return can_add_to(rest, sumwanted-first) or can_add_to(rest, sumwanted)

print(can_add_to([1, 4, 9, 25], 13))
```

This is the same as yours, only more readable. Explanation then:

If there are no numbers, then the answer is "yes" if and only if the wanted sum is zero, and we can say that right away.

Otherwise take the first number (and the rest). You can either use it for the sum or not.

Using it: `can_add_to(rest, sumwanted-first)` tells you whether the *remaining* sum (after subtracting `first`) can be made from the remaining numbers.

Not using it: `can_add_to(rest, sumwanted-first)` tells you whether the *whole* sum can be made from the remaining numbers alone.

The overall answer is "yes" if and only if you can make the sum **with or without** `first`. That's why you take the two sub-answers and `or` them together.